# git subtree vs submodule - embedded code - shared drivers and middleware between PCBs

Tags: git, git-submodules, subtree

I am wondering if I shall use **git** *submodules* or *subtrees* in this specific usecase:

We a have a lot of devices (product families) which contains multiple PCBs with microcontrollers (c code) which controls motors and measures different physical values through sensors and they are connected through network communication (CAN).
In one product we use multiple different PCBs but it is not rare that the same PCB is built into the machine with different application code.

We would not like to use one monorepo because the codebase is big. Basically the idea is to organize the code at PCB level because we usually work on one board at the same time and the application and PCB specific code of other boards are irrelevant when we work on that specific board. Another advantage is that the history of the repository can be more clean this way.

If we have only PCB specific repository then it would be a problem because we would duplicate a lot of code. Example: every board communicates through CAN or uses SPI to read sensor data. Therefore it makes sense to collect these common parts into one or more additional repositories. The question is: how to share the content of these common repositories in git? (e.g. driver or middleware repositories)

Side note: a lot of people recommends the subtree but mostly in those cases when you just need a lib from github and you don't really plan to push content back into the original remote repository.

Comment: Anything that is common should be in a shared submodule.

Comment: Will you have the case where applications are using the common PCB-Version-1, but one of them needs to start using PCB-Version-2? Or either all apps switch or none?

Comment: It might happen maybe in that case we could branch. The reason why we don't create repository for applications is that they are not that complex (couple of c files) so we would like to keep them in the board specific repository.